# GPT4ALL on Windows without WSL, and CPU only

Tags: python, gpt4all

I tried to run the following model from https://github.com/nomic-ai/gpt4all and using the “CPU Interface” on my windows machine.

I get an error that “Current binaries supported are x86 Linux and ARM Macs.” I read that the workaround is to install WSL (windows subsystem for linux) on my windows machine, but I’m not allowed to do that on my work machine (admin locked).

Are there other open source chat LLM models that can be downloaded, run locally on a windows machine, using only Python and its packages, without having to install WSL or nodejs or anything that requires admin rights?

Disclaimer: I noted that this question is only part coding - I ask it here as I need to get past this phase before I can get to exploratory coding and interaction with the model.

Answer (score 0):

After much testing, this works: https://github.com/nomic-ai/pygpt4all

I must say, it is rather slow, but interesting to see how it could actually run on a personal computer.